# How to enable dual boot menu?

Tags: dual-boot, grub

I have Windows in my lap and installed Freya  recently. During installation I choosed something else option and installed in it.  Both install in different directory.  I can see Windows installation directory and other drives.  But it's not showing while booting os.  It boots directly Freya.  I need to select os  while booting.

Comment: directory==partitions ?

Comment: Please see my answer and let me know :)

Comment: sure, i will let you know with in 10 hours, i am not infront of my personal lap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your computer boots straight to Freya:

- Run:

  ```
  sudo update-grub
  sudo reboot
  ```
- If not solved,

  Open terminal and run following commands:

  ```
  sudo mount /dev/sda6 /mnt
  sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda
  sudo update-grub
  ```

  **Note**: In first command `/dev/sda6` is freya `/root` partition.

  If you are not sure about partitions number use `sudo fdisk -l`

  No need to run boot repair using live dvd/usb.

At last, if anything not working, use boot-repair from live usb.

See here for instructions: [Boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

---

If you want to change time for selecting OS in grub:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Change `GRUB_TIMEOUT` value which is 10 by default. Time in seconds. If you keep -1, it will stay indefinitely until you select.

Also make sure, there is a `#` before `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` like:

`#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0`